# Save ArrayList into CSV-File Apache Wicket

Tags: wicket, savefiledialog

How can I "write" an ArrayList in a file, which I can download after the writing? One element in the list is one line in the CSV-file.

For example:
I have an `ArrayList<String> myList = service.getList`
Than I want to write in a File. in a simple client-only-application it would be easy. But I have to do it with **Apache Wicket**. Also it would be nice, to have a Filebrowser, where I can specify, in which directory I want to download it.

I thought, it would work this way:

```
final File filetoSave = new File("Exported Objects.csv");
        Writer writer = null;
        try {

            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filetoSave));
            writer.write("");
            for (obj o : listO) {
                writer.append(o.getasd);

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // report
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
```

But it won't. I have to use a **JBoss-server**. On my local jetty-served it worked, but on the JBoss-server it's not possible to do it this way.
Wicket-version: 1.4.7

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of wicket, since 1.4.7 has security issues. There are at least 15 patch versions available: the most recent 1.4 release is 1.4.22. That said, 1.4 is end of life and you really should consider upgrading to 6.x

Comment: Thx, for your input. The problem is that I cant update it by myself. I have to develop the download-possibility for the company. I know, that we should update. :)

Comment: What do you mean? Should I add this?

Answer (score 0):

See Wicket's [DownloadLink](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/DownloadLink.html) for the download functionality, and use a temporary file (`File.createTempFile()`) to create your downloadable CSV. The way you are creating your file now is in the current working directory of your container. You might not have write privileges in that location, but temp should work.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `Resource` combined with a `ResourceLink`. Generate the file on the fly.